# NavigationBar backgroundColor not coloring statusbar background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I am having some problems coloring the navigationBar. I have tried using different methods from some different tutorials but nothing seems to work the way that I want it to work.
I am using the following code in my AppDelegate:

```
    let navAppeareance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

    navAppeareance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navAppeareance.backgroundColor = .systemRed

    //Setup buttons
    let buttonDone = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .done)
    buttonDone.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navAppeareance.doneButtonAppearance = buttonDone

    let buttonPlain = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .plain)
    buttonPlain.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navAppeareance.buttonAppearance = buttonPlain

    //Set appearances
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navAppeareance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navAppeareance

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemRed
```

The above code yields the following result:
[image: Result of above code]
I want the statusbar to be the same color as the navigationBar, but it takes the color of the backgroundColor of the view.

Comment: I've checked your code in my newly created sample app and it's working perfectly

Comment: @MidhunMP The problem with my code is that the bar somehow becomes transparent when using it. So when I scroll on a tableview with the above code, the text and colors overlap from the tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in AppDelegate

```
let navBarAppearnce = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navBarAppearnce.barTintColor = UIColor.red // the color you want
```

[image: Result]